# Custom Modal Transition Dismiss Animation Runs Desynchronized

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller, uipresentationcontroller

I've been working to implement a custom modal transition that uses a `UIPresentationController` subclass to create and manipulate an additional view during the presentation and dismissal.  Apple helpfully provides an example of how to do this in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPresentationController_class/), but I've hit a snag.

When presenting the modal, my custom view animations work perfectly, but when I dismiss the modal, the animations applied to the custom views in `dismissalTransitionWillBegin` play out of sync with the animations specified by the transition animator object I'm returning from `animationControllerForDismissedController:`.  Specifically, the custom view's animations are ignoring the duration of the transition animation and are always playing very quickly (the duration appears to be around 0.2 seconds).

What could cause `animateAlongsideTransition:completion:` to ignore the duration of the base animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the trouble appears to be a bug in iOS.

No matter how I refactored or simplified my animation code, I always ended up with the same result, so I started to wonder if there might be something in the way my project was set up that was causing the problem.  I dropped my custom modal transition code into a clean project and, lo and behold, it worked perfectly on the first try.

Bit by bit I customized my test app to more closely match my real app and I was eventually able to get the problem to reappear.  Through trial and error I found the combination of factors that was triggering the problem:

1. The presenting view controller is within a `UINavigationController`
2. The presenting view controller's bar button items include an image-based `UIBarButtonItem`
3. The window has a tint color set

When those three conditions are met, the animation block of the `animateAlongsideTransition:` call in `dismissalTransitionWillBegin` will be performed before the animation block of the `animateWithDuration:` call in `animateTransition`.  This seems to prevent the custom view's animations from getting the transition animation's duration.  In my testing, the `animateAlongsideTransition:` animations ran with a duration of 0.215 seconds, which I believe is the default duration.

I have been unable to find any way prevent the issue from occurring other than removing one of the three factors triggering it.  The workaround I ultimately settled on was removing the window's tint color and instead setting a global tint color using `UIView`'s appearance proxy.  There are some side-effects--like `UIAlertView`s' buttons getting tinted--, but for my purposes this was an acceptable trade-off.